# Python : Plotting dataframes over each other on same axis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have two dataframes. One data frame is called `mra2` with the following data:

```
min_date    Full_Name   Quotes  Orders_Not_Quoted   Quotes_To_Orders    Ratio   MA
2019-10-14  Melissa Felix   2   0   2   1.0 
2019-10-15  Melissa Felix   3   2   0   0.0 
2019-10-16  Melissa Felix   4   0   3   0.75    
2019-10-17  Melissa Felix   3   0   2   0.6666666666666666  
2019-10-21  Melissa Felix   2   0   2   1.0 
2019-10-22  Melissa Felix   3   0   2   0.6666666666666666  
2019-10-23  Melissa Felix   3   0   0   0.0 
2019-10-24  Melissa Felix   6   0   2   0.3333333333333333  
2019-10-25  Melissa Felix   4   0   3   0.75    
2019-10-28  Melissa Felix   3   0   1   0.3333333333333333  0.5499999999999999
2019-10-29  Melissa Felix   5   0   2   0.4 0.48999999999999994
2019-10-30  Melissa Felix   3   0   3   1.0 0.59
2019-11-07  Melissa Felix   5   0   2   0.4 0.5549999999999999
2019-11-08  Melissa Felix   5   0   0   0.0 0.4883333333333333
2019-11-09  Melissa Felix   7   0   2   0.2857142857142857  0.41690476190476183
2019-11-14  Melissa Felix   2   0   1   0.5 0.40023809523809517
2019-11-15  Melissa Felix   1   1   0   0.0 0.40023809523809517
2019-11-18  Melissa Felix   7   2   3   0.42857142857142855 0.4097619047619047
2019-11-19  Melissa Felix   4   0   1   0.25    0.3597619047619047
2019-11-20  Melissa Felix   4   0   0   0.0 0.3264285714285714
2019-11-21  Melissa Felix   2   1   1   0.5 0.3364285714285714
2019-11-26  Melissa Felix   3   0   0   0.0 0.23642857142857138
2019-11-27  Melissa Felix   2   0   0   0.0 0.1964285714285714
2019-11-29  Melissa Felix   4   0   0   0.0 0.1964285714285714
```

and mra22 which is mra2 grouped by min_date and full_name:

```
min_date    Full_Name   Quotes  Orders_Not_Quoted   Quotes_To_Orders    Ratio
2019-10-13  Melissa Felix   12  2   7   0.5833333333333334
2019-10-20  Melissa Felix   18  0   9   0.5
2019-10-27  Melissa Felix   11  0   6   0.5454545454545454
2019-11-03  Melissa Felix   17  0   4   0.23529411764705882
2019-11-10  Melissa Felix   3   1   1   0.3333333333333333
2019-11-17  Melissa Felix   17  3   5   0.29411764705882354
2019-11-24  Melissa Felix   9   0   0   0.0
```

When I plot both dataframes as lines I get

```
ax=mra22['Ratio'].plot()
ax2=mra2['MA'].plot()
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22UEr.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T54B.png .

I want the 'Ratio' values to be visualized as bars but when I add 'kind=bar' into the 'plot' script I don't get what I want.

```
ax=mra22['Ratio'].plot(kind='bar')
ax2=mra2['MA'].plot()
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22UEr.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/es0l0.png .

I think this is because the x-axis values are marked differently as bars; (2019-10-13,2019-10-20,etc) as opposed to (2019-10-15,2019-10-22,etc) that was shown when the plot was double line. I changed the x labels to match with

```
ax2=mra2['MA'].plot()
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=mdates.SU))
```

but this didn't result in 1 plot with 'Ratio' displayed as bars and 'MA' displayed as a line.

```
ax=mra22['Ratio'].plot(kind='bar')
ax2=mra2['MA'].plot()
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(byweekday=mdates.SU))
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22UEr.png)

I tried to use plt.show() and display() but that didn't work. How can I get these two plots to overlay on top of eachother with Ratio shown as bars and MA shown as a line?

Comment: This is because pandas bar plots are categorcial, while line plots are numeric. If you use matplotlib methods for plotting, both will be numeric and can be overlayed.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Thank you.